# How to set the row height of listview to fit the image size

Tags: android, listview

I am building a listview that contains two imageviews and a textview. But I am not getting the right look. either the icons become too small or too big or there is a lot of empty space around the rows. If I change the scaletype of imageview to center the icons become too small with a lot of space around. when I change the scaletype to fitcenter the icons become too large. In either case it looks ugly. I changed the layout height of the imageview to match parent the extra space disappeared but the icons became too small. I am using png images of 64x64 pixels and nexus 7 emulator. I am pasting the xml file below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F6F6F6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am confused. please help. Thanks in advance.

I used 128x128 sized icons even that did not help.

Comment: can you attach image/screenshot  what you want to do

Comment: Please refer these links for more info about ListView [Link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) and [Link2](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `android:minHeight` ,set it to the size you want to keep each list view item, so that image come properly which in your case is `64` pixels height

Here goes the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="64dp"
    android:background="#F6F6F6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But will this be a good approach? I mean I will be using different sized icons for different density screens. This will make the size static and will mean that I will have to define different layouts for different screens.

Comment: create list item for each screen density , compare and see accordingly
try to run this with different density and screen sizes and see result

Answer (score 0):

For the imageview provide these two attributes,
android:minHeight and  android:scaleType

Example:

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/minHeight"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Using this scaletype attribute the image automatically adjusts to the required height without any distortion.